# Postgres insert data for timestamp with timezone

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with two columns each of type timestamp with time zone. I want to insert data a interval of one hour(from 4 to 5) for current date.
Timezone is GMT
Example - start_date and end_date of type timestamp with time zone.

Today's date is 2020-06-01

I want 2020-06-01T04:00:00Z in start_date and  2020-06-01T05:00:00Z in end_date.

insert into table (start_date,end_date) values (???)

I am trying something like `'<<today>>'::date + 'T04:00:00Z'` but it gives me error.

Answer (score 1):

According [PostgreSQL documnetation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html) `+ interval` can solve this problem like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`start_date`, `end_date`) 
VALUES (
    '<<today>>'::date + interval '4 hour',
    '<<today>>'::date + interval '5 hour'
);
```

Comment: I want to insert it in GMT

Comment: Here is a strange idea; read the documentation referenced. Particularly section "9.9.3 AT TIME ZONE". @SlavaRozhnev did not provide that the their own benefit - but yours.